# WCF Self hosted REST server (https) keeps asking for client authentication

Tags: wcf, ssl, https, certificate

I created a self hosted WCF REST server (w/o IIS).  When I enable SSL support, I am keep asked for a Client Certification when I test the site in Chrome.

Below is my app.config of which I believe I disabled the client authentication.   Is there anything that I am missing here?

photo :
[Chrome asking for client certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nj8v.png)

App.config code :

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ADConnectorLibrary.Service1Behavior" name="ADConnectorLibrary.ADConnectorLibrary">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="ADConnectorLibrary.IADConnectorLibrary" >
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://ADDRESS:8888/ADConnectorLibrary/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ADConnectorLibrary.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
      **<serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>**
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport">
        **<transport clientCredentialType="None" />**
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is disable the SSL setting when hosting the service in IIS.
[image]
[image]

On my side, I create a console application to host the service and bind the sslcert to the specified port with the following command. when the client calls it via browser, it does not pop up a dialog box and prompted me to select the client certificate.

> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000
>   certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6
>   appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}

Maybe we don't need to open the support client certificate,or disable it.

> clientcertnegotiation=disable

Here is the official document, wish it is useful to you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/add-sslcert
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: I currently am not using IIS for hosting the WCF application.  WCF is self-hosted this solution does not apply to my situation.   Do you happen to know how to set 'Ignore' in self-hosted WCF?

Comment: I have modified the reply, wish it is useful to you.

Comment: clientcertnegotiation=disable did the trick. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using TransportSecurity, I believe you need to assign a certificate to your service otherwise it will not be able to encrypt the message via SSL over HTTPS.

Likewise the client would have to trust that certificate, or will get one of these reponses when the client tries to access the service via HTTPS in a brower, and calls from code will fail.

[image]

You probably need to use netsh, since you are not using IIS. You might need to reseach netsh a bit to fit your needs.

Something like this to register the cert to the port and map to the application guid: This is a pure made up example: `netsh http add sslcert ipport=127.0.0.1:8000 certhash=c20ed305ea705cc4e36b317af6ce35dc03cfb83d appid={c9670020-5288-47ea-70b3-5a13da258012} clientcertnegotiation=enable`

you probably don't need this since you are not apply a certificate:

```
 **<serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>**
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and happy new year!

Comment: I already did Netsh as you mentioned here but I am still prompted for client certification in Chrome, Edge.

Comment: Also when I ignore the 'select certification to authenticate yourself' prompt, I see that the connection is secured. So I suspect there is something in my app.config prompting the user to select client certificate

Comment: @hinewwiner maybe try clearing your SSL cache in Chrome? To clear the SSL state in Chrome, follow these steps:

Click the Google Chrome - Settings icon (Settings) icon, and then click Settings.
Click Show advanced settings.
Under Network, click Change proxy settings. The Internet Properties dialog box appears.
Click the Content tab.
Click Clear SSL state, and then click OK.

Comment: @hinewwiner also make sure the cert is installed in the trusted people store on your cient. pubilc key of course

Comment: I think the server certificate is okay because I get secured connection when I ignore the 'client authentication' prompt.  I think there is something in my app.config requiring the client authentication to pop-up.    In any case, I tried to clean up cache but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: @hinewwiner, hmm okay, I don' think it is the app that causes that. What does the client configuration looks like? Also added a edit to answer.